# iOS - Pure AutoLayout and UIScrollView not scrolling

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, autolayout

This is my first time using UIScrollViews with a pure Autolayout approach. This is what the view hierarchy looks like

```
view
-scrollview
--view1
--view2
--view3
```

scrollview should contain view1|view2|view3 in that order.

I set the scrollviews width, height, centerx and bottom space to superview. The view1, view2 and view3 that are created all have their width and height constraints setup in their updateConstraints method. Additionally, some constraints are provided in code. What is the reason this scrollview is not scrolling from left to right? I have read literally all of the guides I can find online about creating and adding subviews to a UIScrollView programmatically with auto layout. I found some mention about having to provide four different constraints, leading, trailing, top and bottom for each view added as a subview to the scrollview. Are these the only NSLayoutAttributes that one can specify? How do attributes such as NSLayoutAttribueLeft or NSLayoutAttribueRight relate? I have read documentation on Apples website as well, specifically [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html%20link). I am attaching the setup I currently have. Everything is done via code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.dataSource = @[ [[PCCGenericRating alloc] initWithTitle:@"Easiness"
                                                      andMessage:@"WHAT A JOKERRRR"
                                                    andVariatons:@[ @"very easy", @"easy", @"moderate", @"hard", @"very hard"]],

                         [[PCCGenericRating alloc] initWithTitle:@"Joker"
                                                      andMessage:@"WHAT A JOKERRRR"
                                                    andVariatons:@[ @"very easy", @"easy", @"moderate", @"hard", @"very hard"]],

                         [[PCCGenericRating alloc] initWithTitle:@"Difficulty"
                                                      andMessage:@"YOu are not difficult at all"
                                                    andVariatons:@[ @"very easy", @"easy", @"moderate", @"hard", @"very hard"]]
                       ];
    [self initView];
}

- (void)initView {
    CGFloat navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;

    CGFloat heightDifference = navigationBarHeight + statusBarHeight;

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];


    //setup constraints
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                                                     constant:0.0f]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:1.0f
                                                           constant:-heightDifference]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                                                     constant:0.0f]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0f
                                                           constant:0.0]];

    [self.dataSource enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        PCCGenericRating *rating = (PCCGenericRating *)obj;
        PCCGenericRatingView *ratingView = [self createViewWithRating:rating];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:ratingView];

        int multiplier = (idx == 0) ? 1 : (int) (idx + 1) ;
        [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ratingView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                       multiplier:multiplier
                                                                         constant:0.0f]];

        [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ratingView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.scrollView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                                                     constant:0.0f]];
    }];
}

- (PCCGenericRatingView *)createViewWithRating:(PCCGenericRating *)rating {
    PCCGenericRatingView *view = [PCCGenericRatingView genericRatingViewWithTitle:rating.title andMessage:rating.message];
    return view;
}
```

Upon printing out the scrollview constraints, they look okay to me:

```
po self.scrollView.constraints
<__NSArrayM 0x115b051f0>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1145d9290 PCCGenericRatingView:0x114579880.centerX == UIScrollView:0x11458d4b0.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1145d9410 PCCGenericRatingView:0x114579880.centerY == UIScrollView:0x11458d4b0.centerY>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1145d9dd0 PCCGenericRatingView:0x1145d9560.centerX == 2*UIScrollView:0x11458d4b0.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1145d9e40 PCCGenericRatingView:0x1145d9560.centerY == UIScrollView:0x11458d4b0.centerY>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1145da6b0 PCCGenericRatingView:0x1145d9e90.centerX == 3*UIScrollView:0x11458d4b0.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1145da730 PCCGenericRatingView:0x1145d9e90.centerY == UIScrollView:0x11458d4b0.centerY>
)
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image: simulator]

I find it odd that the last element in the datasource is the first view controller showing up in the scrollview, when it should be the last view. It also doesn't scroll left to right as it should.

Comment: Try calling initView from viewWillAppear, as all the dimensions of your layout are not set in viewDidLoad.

Comment: This doesn't change anything.I believe there are some constraints that are not being added..I just don't know what.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your `top_constraint` for the **view1** and `bottom_constraint` for **view3** will be as per your **scrollView's constraints**. Otherwise scrollview's `contentSize: {0, 0}`.

Comment: I think this is the most important thing to consider! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Wherever you are printing your constraints, try printing scrollview.contentSize, it will likely be 0,0 and that is where your problem is. As far as I know, and as you mentioned in your post, you have to explicitly set the subviews of a scrollview to the scrollviews top bottom left and right constraints. Setting these automatically sets the contentSize of the scrollview which will enable it to scroll. It looks like you are only setting centerX and centerY constraints which will not set the scrollviews contentSize to what you need.

Try setting these programatically (this is pseudocode but you get the idea):

- view1.topConstraint = scrollView.topConstraint
- view1.leftConstraint = scrollView.leftConstraint
- view3.bottomConstraint = scrollView.bottomConstraint
- view3.rightConstraint = scrollView.rightConstraint

If you set all of those correctly, your scrollview will scroll properly. Just remember to check the contentsize, and if the contentsize is 0,0 then your constraints aren't properly set up.